# Space Evenly only for the inputs of a form

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a flashcard system where users will see input on the left and right for the front and back of their cards.

I am trying to have the Label above, submit button below and the front and back inputs beside each other.

My attempts have results in all 4 being stacked ontop or beside each other.  Is this something possible with html and css?

**HTML**

```
<div class="view_new_flashcard">
<form method="POST" action="'.newcard($conn).'">
    <input type="hidden" name="PostID" value="'.$PostID.'">
    <input type="hidden" name="MatchUserID" value="'.$UserID.'">
    <label>Enter New Card Information</label>
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" name="FrontSide" placeholder="Front of Card">
    <input type="text" name="BackSide" placeholder="Back of Card">
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="addcard">Add New Card</button>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```css
.view_new_flashcard {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.view_new_flashcard form {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.view_new_flashcard input {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 8px;
    /* width: 100%; */
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="view_new_flashcard">
    <form method="POST" action="'.newcard($conn).'">
        <input type="hidden" name="PostID" value="'.$PostID.'">
        <input type="hidden" name="MatchUserID" value="'.$UserID.'">
        <label>Enter New Card Information</label>
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="FrontSide" placeholder="Front of Card">
        <input type="text" name="BackSide" placeholder="Back of Card">
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" name="addcard">Add New Card</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: According to your description of the expected result, your code example meet the requirements. What is the problem you have exactly?

Comment: I want them to fill 100% of the parent div without going to the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the inputs in a`div` with `display: flex` and use [flex-grow: 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) on the input.

```css
.view_new_flashcard {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.view_new_flashcard form {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: grey;
}

.view_new_flashcard input {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 8px;
  /* width: 100%; */
  height: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0 3px;
}

.view_new_flashcard .input-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="view_new_flashcard">
  <form method="POST" action="'.newcard($conn).'">
    <input type="hidden" name="PostID" value="'.$PostID.'">
    <input type="hidden" name="MatchUserID" value="'.$UserID.'">
    <label>Enter New Card Information</label>
    <br><br>
    <div class="input-container">
      <input type="text" name="FrontSide" placeholder="Front of Card">
      <input type="text" name="BackSide" placeholder="Back of Card">
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="addcard">Add New Card</button>
  </form>
</div>
```